# Signal ALL workers in uWSGI configuration

Tags: python, server, wsgi, uwsgi

I have a uWSGI server with N amount of worker processes. Using the built in signal system I can effectively message the first available worker. I can also do something similar with the built in RPC system.

Does anyone here know of a way to send a signal to all workers?

Basically I would like to be able to notify the worker that it needs to reload a process local cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument when you register a signal is the 'target':

http://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Signals.html#signals-targets

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I read those docs over and over, and still missed that somehow :/